# Problem with Vee-validate and Vuetify, Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$vuetify' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

Hi I have a proble with the integration of Vee-validation and Vuetify: here is my config:

```
import { ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('required', {
  ...required,
  message: '{_field_} can not be empty'
});

Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
```

and this is my code:

```
 <ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" name="Name" rules="required|max:10">
    <v-text-field :label="this.$vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.campaign.link')"
              required
              v-model="campaign.link"
              :error-messages="errors"
     ></v-text-field>
 </ValidationProvider>
```

this is my error trace:

```
 Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$vuetify' of null"

found in

---> <ValidationProvider> 
...
```

when I remove the :label line (it is using i18n) for some plain text, it works, something like this:

```
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" name="Name" rules="required|max:10">
    <v-text-field label="some label"
              required
              v-model="campaign.link"
              :error-messages="errors"
     ></v-text-field>
 </ValidationProvider>
```

I dont have idea, why if I surround a component with ValidationProvider, I lost the access to this object.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `this` in templates

```js
:label="this.$vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.campaign.link')"
        ^^^^
```

just remove `this` and your label should looks like this:

```js
:label="$vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.campaign.link')"
```